# How can I safely handle null values when calling Java methods from Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, nullpointerexception, kotlin-null-safety

How can I handle null safety in Kotlin when interfacing with Java libraries that do not have null safety?

Through research, here are things I found that "work", but are not safe.

1. Using Kotlin's non-null type with a Java method that returns null:
2. Using `!!` operator with a Java method that returns null:
3. Assuming a Java Boolean is never null: In Java, `Boolean` can be `true`, `false`, or `null`, but in Kotlin, `Boolean` can only be `true` or `false`.

In these examples, my Kotlin compiler won't show an error because it doesn't have enough information about whether the Java methods can return null.

Comment: TBH, Kotlin's interface with Java is pretty clean, typically the 3 areas where extra care is required are: Nullability, Mutability (immutable lists etc) and cases where a Java library constructs new Kotlin objects (how to pass in class objects and usage of late init etc).

Comment: As the question, comments, and answers show, you have many options. Which one(s) to choose depends upon this: **What do you _want_ to happen if the Java code returns null where the Kotlin code is expecting non-null?** An immediate exception with a specific helpful message? An immediate generic NullPointerException? No exception unless/until you try to use the value? A default value? Bypassing any code which tries to use the value? — All of those are possible, and most could make sense in the right situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treat it the same way you would in Java. Assume the value might be null unless the documentation for the method that you are getting it from declares that it will not be null. If it does not declare that it will not return null, it is nullable. Treat it exactly as a nullable Kotlin variable. So use `?.`, `?:`, `if (foo != null)`, or `.orEmpty()` as appropriate for the situation.

Java also has non-nullable `boolean`, `long`, `int`, `char`, `byte`, `double`, and `float`. If you see the lowercase type, you know it's not nullable.